# how i know blazor OnInitializedAsync exec in once or twice

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want get data from db once on `OnInitializedAsync`. I try to use `tableLoading` to judue,but it's not work.

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (tableLoading)
        {
            return;
        }
       tableLoading = true;
        users = await userService.GetSome(1, userType);
        _total = await userService.GetCount(userType);
        tableLoading = false;
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitializedAsync");
    }
```

Comment: When using prerendering OnInitializedAsync is called twice. Are you using prerendering?

Comment: I probably know the answer ,i don't use `static` var.

Comment: This is a guess, but maybe what you're seeing is the component rendering the data twice, once when `await userService.GetSome(1, userType);` yields and again on completion.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#persist-prerendered-state) is the official way to solve your problem. You have to persist component state during first load so that your services won't be called second time during second load.

First add `<persist-component-state />` tag helper inside your apps body:

```
<body>
    ...

    <persist-component-state />
</body>
```

Then inject `PersistentComponentState` in your component and use like this:

```
@implements IDisposable
@inject PersistentComponentState ApplicationState

@code {
    private IEnumerable<User> _users;
    private int _total;

    private PersistingComponentStateSubscription _persistingSubscription;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _persistingSubscription = 
            ApplicationState.RegisterOnPersisting(PersistState);
       
        if (!ApplicationState.TryTakeFromJson<IEnumerable<User>>("users", out var restoredUsers))
        {
            _users = await userService.GetSome(1, userType); 
        }
        else
        {
            _users = restoredUsers;
        }

        if (!ApplicationState.TryTakeFromJson<int>("total", out var restoredTotal))
        {
             _total = await userService.GetCount(userType);
        }
        else
        {
            _total = restoredTotal;
        }
    }
        
    private Task PersistState()
    {
        ApplicationState.PersistAsJson("users", _users);
        ApplicationState.PersistAsJson("total", _total);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        _persistingSubscription.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ewww.  That's actually disgusting to look at.  I'm not saying you're wrong, but. . . ewwww.

Comment: Code was actually wrong, fixed it now so thanks for your comment.

Comment: I really work they fix this in the future. This should all be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

> How i know blazor OnInitializedAsync exec in once or twice?

It usually loads twice.

1. Once when the component is initially rendered statically as part of the page.
2. A second time when the browser renders the component.

However, If you want to load it once, in that case, you could go to `_Host.cshtml` and change `render-mode="ServerPrerendered"` to `render-mode="Server"`, and it would be called only once as a result it would then load your data from the database once only.

**Note:** For more information you could refer to the [`official documents here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-initialization-oninitializedasync-2).

Answer (score -1):

I know it's usually loads twice, i want to know when the function is run, how to konw it's run on once or twice. This is my solution.

```cs
static bool first = true;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
           Console.WriteLine("first time");
            return;
        }
Console.WriteLine("second time");
    }
```

Comment: The [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#after-component-render-onafterrenderasync-2) I shared earlier is clearly stated that [`you could check`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#after-component-render-onafterrenderasync-2) again.